# No Such User Here Local Delivery error

Tags: php, email

I'm having issues sending emails from my contact form.

I have my domain on 123-reg to point to my web hosing at shockhosting and the mx records are set to 123-regs.

So when I try using my contact form to go to my email info@example.com it gets this error on the WHM:

No Such User Here

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: If you pointed A record to shockhosting and MX records to 123-reg - you should be creating the mailbox at 123-reg. If you pointed NS records to shockhosting - the mailbox needs to be created at shockhosting. So what's your current setup?